# sort linked list in C++ by using std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I have already used std::sort for array, now I want to use it for linked list
Can I use std::sort for linked list. If it's able, how can I use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because `std::sort` requires random access iterators, and `std::list` provides only bidirectional iterators. Use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may not use standard algorithm `std::sort` with container `std::list` because the algorithm uses `random access iterators` while container `std::list` has only a `bidirectional iterator`.

However `std::list` (and `std::forward_list`) has its own methods `sort`

```
void sort();
template <class Compare> void sort(Compare comp);
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::list<int> l( N );

    std::srand( ( unsigned )std::time( 0 ) );

    std::generate( l.begin(), l.end(), []{ return std::rand() % N; } );

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x <<' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    l.sort();

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x <<' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1 
1 2 3 3 5 5 6 6 7 9
```